# Dynamic programatical binding of OpenGL ES compute shader program arguments

Tags: opengl-es, parameter-passing, shader

I am new to OpenGL ES. I am using compute shader alone for compute intensive works to port OpenCL and CUDA programs. I have a problem in binding compute shader program parameters dynamically programically. I am unsure this is possible in OpenCL ES. I have multiple compute only shader programs, say, 2 in the following code. From shader 2, outputs of shader 1 is used as inputs. Parameters are integer and float numbers and shader storage buffer arrays as in the following codes. Obviously my codes doesn't work. Parameters seem to bound to locations specified in shader codes. How can I dynamically attach shader storage buffers to shader parameters?

How can I achieve this dynamic binding of parameters programatically? Thanks in advance.

```
static const char gComputeShader1[] =
        R"(#version 320 es
layout(local_size_x = 32) in;
uniform int optype;
uniform float opvalue;
layout(binding = 0) readonly buffer Input0 {
    float data1[];
} input0;
layout(binding = 1) readonly buffer Input1 {
    float data2[];
} input1;
layout(binding = 2) writeonly buffer Output {
     float data3[];
} output0;

void main() {
    uint idx = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    float f = input0.data1[idx] + input1.data2[idx];
    output0.data3[idx] = f;
}
)";

static const char gComputeShader2[] =
        R"(#version 320 es
layout(local_size_x = 32) in;
uniform int optype;
uniform float opvalue;
layout(binding = 0) readonly buffer Input0 {
    float data1[];
} input0;
layout(binding = 1) readonly buffer Input1 {
    float data2[];
} input1;
layout(binding = 2) writeonly buffer Output {
     float data3[];
} output0;

void main() {
    uint idx = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    float f = input0.data1[idx] + input1.data2[idx];
    output0.data3[idx] = f;
}
)";

void createSSBufferObject(GLuint& ssbo, GLuint index, float* pIn, GLuint count) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, count * sizeof(float), pIn, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, index, ssbo);
}

    GLuint SSBO0;
    GLuint SSBO1;
    GLuint SSBO2;

    createSSBufferObject(SSBO0, 0, f0, arraySize);
    createSSBufferObject(SSBO1, 1, f1, arraySize);
    createSSBufferObject(SSBO2, 2, NULL, arraySize);

    // first shader call
    glUseProgram(computeProgram1);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 0, SSBO0);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 1, SSBO1);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 2, SSBO2);
    glDispatchCompute(1000,1,1);   // arraySize/local_size_x
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    // retrieve data here.
    
    // second shader call with different parametes
    // need to change parameter values and SSBOs dynamically.
    glUseProgram(computeProgram2);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 2, SSBO0);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 1, SSBO1);
    linkSSBufferObject(computeProgram1, 0, SSBO2);
    glDispatchCompute(1000,1,1);   // arraySize/local_size_x
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    // retrieve data here.
```

I try to use the following API to bind shader storage buffer arrays to shader parameters. I need a way to achieve this.

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, index, ssbo);
```

Comment: Actually this code works. I probably had other errors that made this code didn't work.